# TypeError in Ejs File

Tags: javascript, ejs

I am getting `Type Error` in my `console` for this code. However, when I run this function, I do get the output. but right after it this error appears. How can I resolve this?

> TypeError:
> C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\Development\blogsite\starting
> files\blogsite\views\home.ejs:5

```js
<p><%=homeContent%></p>
<%  for( i=0 ;i<=postsItem.length;i++){ %>
<% console.log(postsItem[i].title);%>
<%  }; %>
<%- include('partials/footer') %>
```

I have tested separately the code line. I am getting error at without `for` loop and it works fine but as soon as I put this in `for` loop, it shows that error.

Comment: don't `console.log` it there...rather do it in `script` tag

Comment: Are you sure you need `i<=postsItem.length` instead of `i<postsItem.length`? Did you get `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')`?

Comment: @qrsngky you are right. I was using an array's length as the upper bond limit in the for loop but in going through an array, the count always start from zero. So every time for loop is executed, it will look for an additional element at the end of it which do not exists. I changed postsItem.length to postsItem.length-1 and the error got resolved.